# How do I change the transparency of the cursor? (Python)

Tags: python, windows, cursor

I'm trying to find a way to gradient the transparency of the cursor for a project, but I can't find any modules or anything about it. I've tried looking through the win32 API and there was nothing related to cursor transparency, and I've tried googling it, but I don't get any useful results. If someone could tell me how to change the cursors transparency it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.